# How to convert fbx with animations to dae

Tags: animation, ios, fbx, collada

I am making an ARKit app, and I need to implement animations. Our 3D artist has provided these files as fbx with animations.

All resources I find online about animated models in ARKit talk about dae (Collada) files with animation.

Is there a way to convert an fbx file with animations to a dae file containing the animations?

I tried asking our artist to export a DAE file, but that didn't appear to work as he has no experience with DAE files. The animation didn't seem to play.

I have also tried an online converter (http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/), but that failed to perform the conversion.

Comment: Presumably you started by [searching for conversion strategies that have already been described](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+fbx+to+dae). What have you tried so far based on your research?

Comment: Yes I did, edited my question to indicate what I tried. Currently installing CAD software to try to convert it myself.